# String includes and parsed date object don't work the expected way

Tags: javascript, string, date, include

I am just puzzled by this piece of code. I've spent a few hours trying to figure out why this happens. I would highly appreciate if someone with more knowledge could explain this to me :).

```js
let day = "Monday";
let someDate = new Date(2021, 7, 2);
let stringDate = someDate.toString().substring(0, 4);

console.log(day)
console.log(stringDate)
console.log(typeof day)
console.log(typeof day)

console.log(day.includes(stringDate));
```

Comment: Don't ever relay on anything specific being present in `Date.prototype.toString()`; it's output is unspecified and is up to the JS engine. Use a standard-output method like `.toISOString()` or `.toGMTString()`.

Comment: @dandavis—the format of [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is specified exactly by EMCA 262 in the [*ToDateString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-todatestring) algorithm. The only implementation dependent part is the timezone name, the rest has been standardised since ECMAScript 2018 (ed 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually check your `stringDate` variable in detail, you'll notice that it actually is `Mon`  and not just `Mon`. That extra space makes the `.includes` fail.

After all, `.slice(0, 4)` takes the first 4 characters of the string.

On another note, shouldn't `someData.toString()` give different results depending on the language (settings) that the browser/OS is set to? In short, don't attempt to try something like this in actual projects.

Comment: God, I am so dumb. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The format of *Date.prototype.toString* is specified by ECMA-262 and does not depend on browser language. However it is affected by the host regional settings for timezone, which may offset the result by +14 to -10 hours from the UTC equivalent.

Comment: @RobG Gotcha. I thought I had it appear in different languages in the past (my browser/OS used to be in Dutch), but seems I just misremember. I do know about `Date` being very... _caring about time zones_, which would indeed influence the week of the day.